# Solaris 11 manifest-import does not automatically import my manifest

Tags: solaris, smf

I have a manifest XML file. When I copy my XML to `/var/svc/manifest/` and restart manifest-import service `sudo svcadm restart svc:/system/manifest-import`, the service does not appear in my service list.

However, when I import it manually, i.e. `sudo svccfg import myxml.xml`, it works and appears in `svcs -l` list.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Going from [Managing System Services in Oracle® Solaris 11.2](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E36784_01/html/E36820/importapplycfg.html), under *Importing and Applying Manifests and Profiles*, it says:

> Recommended best practice is to put your manifest and profile files in the standard locations and restart the manifest-import service rather than use the svccfg import or svccfg apply commands.

Additionally, the table under *Repository Layers* indicates:

> Note that /var/svc/manifest is deprecated as a standard location and should not be used for new manifests.

I then found the section on [Service Configuration Repository](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E36784_01/html/E36820/screpository.html), where under *Service Bundles* it says:

> The standard location for manifests is /lib/svc/manifest.